# gmap3 marker icon shadow not showing up

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers, jquery-gmap3

I have created this map selection tool with the Gmap3 library and I can get the marker to show up but for some reason I can't get the shadow values to show up.  I have put both the icon and shadow values into a variable so that you can call the variable when you need to.  Any help would be appreciated.

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryanverdel/d3dzh/)**

Source Script

```
    $(document).ready(function() {  

    //////// GMAP3 JSON ARRAY //////// 

    var mapOpts = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    mapTypeControl: true,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
    navigationControl: true,
    scrollwheel: true,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
    streetViewControl: false,
    }; 

$(".gmap3").gmap3({
        map:{
        options: mapOpts
        }

    });

$.mapArray = function(){

$('#show_array').click(function(){

$('.gmap3').gmap3('clear', 'markers');

  var coordinates = $("#geofenceCoords_array").val();
  var jsonObj = jQuery.parseJSON(coordinates);
  var addBtn = $("#show_array"); 

  var iconValues =
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.mindboxdesigns.com/test-images/map_marker_default.png', //icon url
  new google.maps.Size(28.0, 43.0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(14.0, 43.0));


  var shadowValues =
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.mindboxdesigns.com/test-images/map_marker_default_shadow.png', //icon shadow url
  new google.maps.Size(50.0, 43.0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(14.0, 43.0)); 

    $(".gmap3").gmap3({
    getlatlng:{
        callback: function(results){
          var markers=[];
          $.each(jsonObj, function(i, item) {

          var marker = new Object();
              marker.lat = jsonObj[i].latitude;
              marker.lng = jsonObj[i].longitude;
              marker.options = new Object();
              marker.options.icon = iconValues;
              marker.options.shadow = shadowValues;
              markers.push(marker);
          });


          $(".gmap3").gmap3({
            marker:{
              values: markers,
              options: {draggable: false,
              animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
              },

          },
          autofit:{maxZoom: 14},
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
}

//////// GMAP3 DRAG AND DROP ////////

 $.mapDrop = function(){

  var iconValues =
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.mindboxdesigns.com/test-images/map_marker_default.png', //icon url
  new google.maps.Size(28.0, 43.0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(14.0, 43.0));

  var shadowValues =
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.mindboxdesigns.com/test-images/map_marker_default_shadow.png', //icon shadow url
  new google.maps.Size(50.0, 43.0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(14.0, 43.0)); 

 function genId() {
        return '' + (new Date()).getTime();
    }

    function addMarker(map, event) {
        if (markerCount < 10) {
            var uid = genId();
            $(this).gmap3({
                marker: {
                    latLng: event.latLng,
                    options: {
                        draggable: true,
                        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                        icon: iconValues,
                        shadow: shadowValues
                    },
                    events: {
                        click: function() {
                            clearMarker(uid);
                        },
                        dragend: listMarkers
                    },
                    id: uid
                }
            });
            markerCount++;
            listMarkers();

        } else {
            return false;
        };
    }
    function listMarkers() {
        $(".gmap3").gmap3({
            get: {
                all: true,
                callback: function(results) {
                    var coords = '';
                    $("#geofenceCoords_dragndrop").empty();

                    $.each(results, function (i, marker) {
                        //$("#inputArray").append('{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() + '},' + '<br>');
                        coords+= '  {"latitude":'  + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() +'},\n';
                    });
                    $("#geofenceCoords_dragndrop").val('['+'\n'+coords.substr(0, (coords.length-2))+'\n]'); 
                }
            }
        });
    }
    function clearMarker(uid) {
        $('.gmap3').gmap3({
            clear: {
                id: uid,
                callback: function() {
                    listMarkers();
                    markerCount--;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var markerCount = 0;

    $(".gmap3").gmap3({
        map: {
            options: mapOpts,
            events: {
                click: addMarker
            }
        }
    });

 }

//////// GMAP3 ADDRESS ////////

  $.mapAddress = function(){



var mapOpts = {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeControl: true,
        mapTypeControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
        },
        navigationControl: true,
        scrollwheel: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
        streetViewControl: false,
    };

  var iconValues =
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.mindboxdesigns.com/test-images/map_marker_default.png', //icon url
  new google.maps.Size(28.0, 43.0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(14.0, 43.0));

  var shadowValues =
  new google.maps.MarkerImage('http://www.mindboxdesigns.com/test-images/map_marker_default_shadow.png', //icon shadow url
  new google.maps.Size(50.0, 43.0),
  new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
  new google.maps.Point(14.0, 43.0)); 


    $(".gmap3").gmap3({
        map:{
        options: mapOpts
        }

    });

    setTimeout(function() {
    $('<span>').attr({ class: 'deleteIcon'}).appendTo(".gmap3");
    }, 200);

    $('#test-ok').click(function(){
      var addr = $('#test-address').val();
      if ( !addr || !addr.length ) return;
      $(".gmap3").gmap3({
        getlatlng:{
          address:  addr,

          callback: function(results){

            if ( !results ) return;

            if (markerCount < 10) {
            $(this).gmap3({
              marker:{

                latLng:results[0].geometry.location,
                options:{
                icon: iconValues,
                shadow: shadowValues
                },
                map:{

                  center: true,

                },

              },
              autofit:{maxZoom: 14},

            });
            listMarkers();
            markerCount++;
            $('#test-address').val("");

            }else {
                $('#test-address').val("limit Reached");
                $('#test-address').css('color','red');
                $('#test-address').attr('readonly','readonly');
            return false;
        };

          }
        }
       });
       });

    function listMarkers() {
        $(".gmap3").gmap3({
            get: {
                all: true,
                callback: function(results) {
                    var coords = '';
                    //$("#geofenceCoords_address").val("");

                    $.each(results, function (i, marker) {
                        //$("#inputArray").append('{"latitude":' + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() + '},' + '<br>');
                        coords+= '  {"latitude":'  + marker.position.lat() + ', ' + '"longitude":' + marker.position.lng() +'},\n';
                    });
                    $("#geofenceCoords_address").val('['+'\n'+coords.substr(0, (coords.length-2))+'\n]');   
                }
            }
        });
    }

    var markerCount = 0;

    $('.gmap3').on('click', '.deleteIcon', function(){                      
    //alert("Handler");
    if(markerCount <= 10){
        markerCount = 0;
    }
    $('.gmap3').gmap3('clear', 'markers');
    $("#geofenceCoords_address").val('');
    $('#test-address').val('');
    $('#test-address').css('color','black');
    $('#test-address').removeAttr('readonly');

    });

    $('#test-address').keypress(function(e){
      if (e.keyCode == 13){
        $('#test-ok').click();
      }
      });
  }

//////// JSON ARRAY VALIDATION ////////


$('#geofenceCoords_array').on('focusout keyup', function (e) {
    var fieldValue = $(this).val(),
    json;

     try {
    json = JSON.parse(fieldValue);
    if (json.length > 3) {
        throw new Error("E_TOO_MANY_COORD");
    }

    _.each(json, function (coordinate) {
        if (!_.has(coordinate, 'latitude') || !_.has(coordinate, 'longitude')) {
            throw new Error("E_INVALID_COORD");
        }
    });

    } catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);
    // handle your invalid json and return to stop further execution
    if (e.message === "E_TOO_MANY_COORD") {
        $('#errorMessage').text("You cannot exeed more than 3 coordiniates");
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass('error');
        $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
    } else if (e.message === "E_INVALID_COORD") {
        $('#errorMessage').html("Please provide valid coordinate pairs:<br> [{\"latitude\":33.851871,\"longitude\":-84.364336}]");
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass('warning');
        $('#geofenceCoords_array').css({
            'border': '1px solid black'
        });
        $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
    }

    return;
}

$('#arrayNum').text(json.length);
$('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass("hide");
$('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('enabled');
$('#errorMessage').text("");
$('#geofenceCoords_array').css({
    'border': '1px solid black'
});

if ($('#arrayNum').text() == 0) {
    $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
}

});

$('#geofenceCoords_array').on('focusout mouseout', function (e) {

var fieldValue = $(this).val(),
    json;

if (e.which === 8) return;

try {
    json = JSON.parse(fieldValue);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);

    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
        $('#errorMessage').text("Please use valid json");
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass('error');
        $('#geofenceCoords_array').css({
            'border': '1px solid red'
        });
        $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
    }

    if (fieldValue === "") {
        $("#arrayNum").text("0");
        $('#geofenceCoords_array').css({
            'border': '1px solid black'
        });
        $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass('hide');
    }
    return;
}

});

$('html,body').on('mousemove', function (e) {

var fieldValue = $("#geofenceCoords_array").val(),
    json;

if (e.which === 8) return;

try {
    json = JSON.parse(fieldValue);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e.message);

    if (e instanceof SyntaxError) {
        $('#errorMessage').text("Please use valid json");
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass('error');
        $('#geofenceCoords_array').css({
            'border': '1px solid red'
        });
        $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
    }

    if (fieldValue === "") {
        $("#arrayNum").text("0");
        $('#geofenceCoords_array').css({
            'border': '1px solid black'
        });
        $('#show_array').removeClass().addClass('disabled');
        $('#errorMessage').removeClass().addClass('hide');
    }
    return;
}
});


//////// MAP TRANSITIONS ////////

$('#default_selection').prop("checked",true);
$('#default_selection').attr("checked",true);


$('#show_array').bind('DOMNodeInserted DOMSubtreeModified DOMNodeRemoved', function(event) {
     if($("#show_array").hasClass('enabled')){
     $.mapArray();
     }
 });


 $("[name=mapSelect]").change(function() {
    $('.gmap3').gmap3('destroy');


    if($(this).val() == 'JSONArray'){
    $('.gmap3').attr("id","newId1");
    $(".gmap3").gmap3({
        map:{options: mapOpts}
    });
    $("#geofenceCoords_dragndrop").val("");
    $("#geofenceCoords_address").val("");
    $.mapArray();
    }

    if($(this).val() == 'dragnDrop'){
    $('.gmap3').attr("id","newId2");
    $(".gmap3").gmap3({
        map:{options: mapOpts}
    });
    $("#geofenceCoords_array").val("");
    $("#geofenceCoords_address").val("");
    $.mapDrop();
    }

    if($(this).val() == 'addrSelect'){
    $('.gmap3').attr("id","newId3");
    $(".gmap3").gmap3({
        map:{options: mapOpts}
    });
    $("#geofenceCoords_array").val("");
    $("#geofenceCoords_address").val("");
    $("#geofenceCoords_dragndrop").val("");
    $.mapAddress();
    }


});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like shadows are deprecated with the 3.14 + versions of GMaps. Darn.

from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#ComplexIcons

*Shadows will not be available when the Visual Refresh mode is enabled, and will be deprecated in version 3.14.*

from: [Shadows on Google Maps visualRefresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470063/shadows-on-google-maps-visualrefresh)

*You can create your marker icon with a shadow.

Or make a custom overlay for your markers which includes a shadow (i.e. not the google.maps.Marker object).

It is now more work, but still possible, as it is no longer the default behavior*.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That's a darn shame.  I wonder why they took it away? It can still be not the default behavior but they could have left the option.  Oh well, looks like I will be hard coding the shadow in.