# How to use google map marker one image over another as marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I searched a lot over internet but did not find correct solution for the problem. i have to display  marker on google map using lat long . I have two images to display as marker one image will work as background and another small image will display over it how can i do this.I am using javascript map api for this.

Note: i can't use photoshop to make these two image as one

Comment: What image are you trying to produce. Are you putting a label? Why not create multiple images with possible combinations. Google Maps only allow you to use one image.

Comment: related question: [Marker shadows in Google Maps v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18902361/marker-shadows-in-google-maps-v3) (the marker shadow is just a second image)

Comment: Note: Marker shadows were removed in version 3.14 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored.       Url: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Google maps utility library called [RichMarker](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-rich-marker) that allows you to use HTML DOM as markers. Using HTML and CSS you can embed your images.

Here is [demo](https://googlemaps.github.io/js-rich-marker/examples/richmarker.html) of the utility.

[image]

You might be able to implement the solution provided here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1782662/1109352

You will be using imbedded CSS instead