# Custom icon anchor point in google maps static API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

I try to set the anchor point of my custom marker to the center with the `shadow:false` parameter but it seems to be ignored:

This is the image without custom marker:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1024x512&path=weight:3|color:0x000000FF|enc:apeiH_h_M{H}LqFjJ_CkFsB_H}@mFUcG]qFm@mt@uM\&markers=48.85777,2.2952&markers=48.86493,2.31033`

[image: without custom marker]
The same image with the custom marker and no shadow parameter:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1024x512&path=weight:3|color:0x000000FF|enc:apeiH_h_M{H}LqFjJ_CkFsB_H}@mFUcG]qFm@mt@uM\&markers=icon:url|48.85777,2.2952&markers=48.86493,2.31033`

[image]

The same image with the custom marker and shadow parameter set to false:

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=1024x512&path=weight:3|color:0x000000FF|enc:apeiH_h_M{H}LqFjJ_CkFsB_H}@mFUcG]qFm@mt@uM\&markers=shadow:false|icon:url|48.85777,2.2952&markers=48.86493,2.31033`

[image]

Comment: I think your current custom marker image has a shadow as ["Marker shadows were removed in version 3.14 of the Google Maps JavaScript API. Any shadows specified programmatically will be ignored."](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons) As for supporting details,here is a previous SO question regarding [marker shadows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470063/shadows-on-google-maps-visualrefresh). And in the example for [custom icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons) there is no shadows.I hope this helps

Comment: It seems that the french documentation hasn't been updated (I reported that to google). Nevertheless the english one states that: "The anchor point of a custom icon is set as the center of the image." which is no the case if I remove the shadow parameter

Comment: What is `url` in your posted snippet?  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The `url` is `http://g oo.gl/fMjXd2` (stackoverflow does'nt allow short url to be posted)

Comment: Possibly related issue in the issue tracker [Issue 6126: Bug: Markers anchor point behaviour changed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6126) (is marked obsolete)

Comment: Feature request: [Issue 2185: Anchor Position on Custom Markers](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2185)

Comment: possibly related issue in the issue tracker: [Issue 6104: Bug: Custom icons started showing at wrong location, without shadow](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=6104)

Comment: Created an [issue in the tracker: Issue 9713: Bug: Custom Icons anchor in wrong place per documentation](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9713)

Comment: For those interested on the issue, A fix has been provided by Google, it's simply a change in the documentation which states: "The anchor point of a custom icon is set as the bottom center of the image.".... Better to say that this is not the intended fix. https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9713

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On January 27, 2017 Google reported that [issue 2185](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=2185) has been fixed. So, from now on you can define a position of anchor for custom markers in Static Maps API.

The documentation was also updated:

> You may specify an anchor point for the custom icon. The anchor point sets how the icon is placed in relation to the specified markers locations. By default, the anchor point of a custom icon is the bottom center of the icon image. You can specify a different anchor point using the anchor descriptor in conjunction with your icon. Set the anchor as an x,y point of the icon (such as 10,5), or as a predefined alignment using one of the following values: top, bottom, left, right, center, topleft, topright, bottomleft, or bottomright.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/start#CustomIcons

So you can rewrite your example now as

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x512&path=weight:3|color:0x000000FF|enc:apeiH_h_M{H}LqFjJ_CkFsB_H}@mFUcG]qFm@mt@uM\&markers=anchor:center|icon:http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FavYzpd|48.85777,2.2952&markers=48.86493,2.31033&center=48.85777,2.2952`

[image: centeredImage]

Answer (score 0):

How about setting a `center`parameter in your query?

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x512&path=weight:3|color:0x000000FF|enc:apeiH_h_M{H}LqFjJ_CkFsB_H}@mFUcG]qFm@mt@uM\&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FavYzpd|48.85777,2.2952&markers=48.86493,2.31033&center=48.85777,2.2952
```

result:
[image: centeredImage]

Even though the map is actually centered, The icon is not upon the starting place... this should be fixed somehow. :/

**EDIT**
So... here you have my very ugly workaround: just re-set your marker's Lat value. By try and error I got this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=640x512&path=weight:3|color:0x000000FF|enc:apeiH_h_M{H}LqFjJ_CkFsB_H}@mFUcG]qFm@mt@uM\&markers=icon:http%3A%2F%2Fgoo.gl%2FavYzpd|48.857,2.2952&markers=48.86453,2.31033
```

With this result:
[image: uglyWA]

Apparently, with this level of zoom and with my particular icon, it's been enough with a subtraction of 0.00077 in the Lat value of the marker.

### FINAL CONCLUSION

Actually there is no way to center the image right from the URL request. On the other hand, we can draw custom icons that fit our purposes. Just adding some margin up in the icon (transparent space) should make the trick.

Comment: The issue is not about centering the map

Comment: The given solution isn't acceptable because it works only for a given lon/lat/zoom

Comment: The only acceptable option I can think of, is adding some transparent space (margin) up in the icon